# Busca de endereço no Google Maps para Android?

Tags: android, geolocalização, google-maps-android-api-2

Como faço para buscar um endereço no Google Maps para Android, a partir do nome do local?

Comment: através de que contexto? um app com um EditText fazendo uma consulta e o mapa mostrando a localização, um ponteiro buscando direto no mapa  e te mostrando uma determinada posição ou ainda você buscando sua localização em tempo real, através de gps? existem várias possibilidades...

Comment: Isso...através de um EditText, digitar o nome de determinado endereço e mostrar o resultado no mapa. Eu já possuo a activity mapa, o que necessito agora é adicionar essa barra de busca.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar esta função:

```
adderess = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3));
// get address in string for used location for the map

/* get latitude and longitude from the adderress */

Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
try
{
    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(adderess, 5);
    if (addresses.size() > 0)
    {
        Double lat = (double) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude());
        Double lon = (double) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude());

        Log.d("lat-long", "" + lat + "......." + lon);
        final LatLng user = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        /*used marker for show the location */
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(user)
            .title(adderess)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(user, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Como posso fazer para conectar esse código a um EditText?